# OnsenUI AngularJS data binding not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui, 2-way-object-databinding

I create a simple example of what I'm about to do:

```js
ons.bootstrap()
  .controller('AppController', function($scope) {
    $scope.x = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
      $scope.x = $scope.x + 1;
    }, 500)
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/onsen/1.3.15/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>

<ons-page ng-controller="AppController">
  <ons-list>
    <ons-list-header>Switch</ons-list-header>
    <ons-list-item>
      <br/>
      This value should change every 500 milisecond: {{ x }}
      <br/>
    </ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item>
      <div class="center">
        Switch is {{ switch ? 'on' : 'off' }}
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <ons-switch ng-model="data.switch"></ons-switch>
      </div>
    </ons-list-item>
  </ons-list>
</ons-page>
```

As a normal angular (with [two-way data binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04)) application any change in controller will result the view update and vise versa.
But in combination with [OnsenUI](https://onsen.io) view update only happens when one onsen component changes updates the view. is there any way to inform onsen about what happened (need of view Update).

Comment: use `$interval` service instead of `setInterval()` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

```
ons.bootstrap()
.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
 $scope.x = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
   $scope.$evalAsync(function () {
                $scope.x = $scope.x + 1;
            });

 }, 500)
});
```

**Edit:**

Or use  `$interval` as @Pankaj Parkar said like this.before use  `$interval` you should inject this service in your controller.

```
 $interval(function () {
   $scope.x = $scope.x + 1;               
 }, 500);
```

Comment: why not `$interval`? instead of having `$evalAsync` inside `setInterval`

Comment: I think that  `$evalAsync` is better than `$interval` for performance. may be!

Comment: @evalAsync wouldn't be faster, AFAIK `$applyAsync`(angular 1.3+) would perform well.. Ideally correct solution would be to use `$interval` only..

Comment: see this article http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2751-scope-applyasync-vs-scope-evalasync-in-angularjs-1-3.htm